# compare two dates in psql

Tags: mysql, psql

I have to compare two dates where  a date column is present in the table with format yyyy-mm-dd. I have to compare the table column date with  current date  and if the difference is greater than 7 then the query should be updated.I hope you guys understood my problem.Thanks for any ideas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

update table set column =
case when DATE_PART('day',now()-column) >5 then now()
else column
end

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is DateDiff;

Try:

```
SELECT DATEDIFF("2017-01-01", "2016-12-24");
```

So, Your final query will be something like this,

```
UPDATE table_name SET field_name='New value' Where DATEDIFF(Your_Date_field_on_db, DATE(NOW()))>7;
```